# Switch in UIAlert Controller programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch, uialertcontroller

I am creating an registration dialog in swift with 3 text field and one Switch and I successfully add three text field two the Alert. The following code shows the same.

```
 let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Register", message: "", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
        // ...

        exit(0)
    }
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Sign UP", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // ...
        let name0 = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
        print("Text field: \(name0.text)")

        let email1 = alertController.textFields![1] as UITextField
        print("Text field: \(email1.text)")

        let company2 = alertController.textFields![2] as UITextField
        print("Text field: \(company2.text)")


    }

    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Name"
        textField.keyboardType = .EmailAddress
    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
        textField.secureTextEntry = false
    }

    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Company"
        textField.secureTextEntry = false
    }


            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
                // ...
            }
```

Now I need to add a switch programmatically to the Alert View.We are doing this in Swift2. Is it possible?, i am new to Swift.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may help you.

Add this method call `alertController.view.addSubview(createSwitch())`  in above code after  `alertController.addAction(OKAction)`.

```
func createSwitch () -> UISwitch{


    let switchControl = UISwitch(frame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 0, 0));
    switchControl.on = true
    switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false);
    switchControl.addTarget(self, action: "switchValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged);
    return switchControl
}

func switchValueDidChange(sender:UISwitch!){

    print("Switch Value : \(sender.on))")
}
```

OutPut :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there is any way to show that switch below the last text field (company). Like a switch that helps agree or disagree terms.

Comment: I tried hard for same, to put switch below last text field .But not succeeded. If you find then please post your code.Thanks

Comment: Do u know is there is any way to put a small space between two text fields?

Comment: I got another method   http://radar.oreilly.com/2014/01/transcending-uialertview-on-ios-7.html

Comment: Updating your code:

    func createSwitch () -> UISwitch{
        
        let switchControl = UISwitch(frame: CGRect(x:10, y:10, width:0, height:0));
        switchControl.isOn = true
        switchControl.setOn(true, animated: false);
        switchControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(switchValueDidChange), for: .valueChanged);

        return switchControl
    }

    @objc
    func switchValueDidChange(sender: UISwitch!){
        
        print("Switch Value : \(sender.isOn))")
    }

Answer (score 7):

You can use the RightView of the TextField to add a button.  Adding a switch would be nice but the switch does not fit into the TextField height nor can you change the height.  To this end you can add a button and use images to make a TickBox.

[image: AlertController with TickBox]

I have ripped this out of a project so the example image is a little more than below.

In the ViewController header add the TextField Delegate

```
@interface CustomTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Then create your AlertController and add the TextField

```
// create an alert controller
UIAlertController *alertWithText = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:body preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

// create the actions handled by each button
UIAlertAction *action1 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];

UIAlertAction *action2 = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

}];

// add the actions to the alert
[alertWithText addAction:action1];
[alertWithText addAction:action2];

// Establish the weak self reference
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[alertWithText addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {

    // Create button
    UIButton *checkbox = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [checkbox setFrame:CGRectMake(2 , 2, 18, 18)];  // Not sure about size
    [checkbox setTag:1];
    [checkbox addTarget:weakSelf action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Setup image for button
    [checkbox.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [checkbox setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted:TRUE];

    // Setup the right view in the text field
    [textField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [textField setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
    [textField setRightView:checkbox];

    // Setup Tag so the textfield can be identified
    [textField setTag:-1];
    [textField setDelegate:weakSelf];

    // Setup textfield
    [textField setText:@"Essential"];  // Could be place holder text

}];

[self presentViewController:alertWithText animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You need to stop the textfield from editing if you purely want that line to be a tick.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if(textField.tag == -1){
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

And your action for your button

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(UIButton*)sender {

    if(sender.selected){
        [sender setSelected:FALSE];
    } else {
        [sender setSelected:TRUE];
    }
}
```

Here are some tick box images too (there are plenty out there, you could even make a switch and try and animate).

[image: Unchecked Box][image: Checked Box]

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for Objective C.  It doesn't use text fields but it does add a `UISwitch` to a `UIAlertController` as asked in the main question.  I didn't find anything on SO that does exactly this so I'm posting this answer here, rather than posting another question that will get dinged as a duplicate.

This solution is used to enable users to sort a `UITableView` menu (of a list of projects...)

Thanks to the answer by @technerd, I also made the `UISwitch` change the text of a `UILabel` that is also on the same `UIAlertController` view.  It uses KVC (Key-Value Coding) in the layer to pass the `UILabel` id to the target action when the `UISwitch` value is changed. (See the `setOrderLabelText` method in the code)

I was also trying to get around the trick of adding newlines ("\n\n\n\n") to the title or message to artificially move things around, by using constraints.

I used a horizontal `UIStackView` to hold the `UISwitch` and it's corresponding `UILabel`, and then used constraints to set the top anchor of the `UIStack` and a height constraint on the `UIAlertController` view to make it big enough to contain the `UIStackView` and the UIAlertController title.

I don't think it is possible to get the height of the title of the `UIAlertController` or the height of the action buttons.  So I came up with values that worked well on an iPhone X and an iPad 2.  As in other SO answers, I will likely come up with a home grown (or find one on GitHub) solution to make this more robust.  But since I got this far and got so much from other awesome SO answers, I wanted to give back a bit and share my results.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

And here's the code:

```
// using KVC, set the label text based on the label tag and toggle the tag
- (void)setOrderLabelText:(UISwitch *)orderSwitch {
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[orderSwitch.layer valueForKey:@"label"];

    label.text = label.tag ? @"Ascending" : @"Descending";

    label.tag = label.tag ? 0 : 1;

}

// sort the data based on the user's selections
- (IBAction)sort:(UIButton *)sortButton {    
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.text = @"Ascending";
    label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor;
    label.tag = 0;
    [label sizeToFit];

    UISwitch *orderSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
    orderSwitch.on = YES;
    [orderSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];

    // allow the switch to change the text in the label using KVC (key-value coding)
    [orderSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(setOrderLabelText:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [orderSwitch.layer setValue:label forKey:@"label"];

    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] init];
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    stackView.spacing = 8;

    [stackView addArrangedSubview:orderSwitch];
    [stackView addArrangedSubview:label];

    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                alertControllerWithTitle: @"Sort Projects By"
                                message: nil
                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *createdButton = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Created"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                      [self sortBy:@"created" ascending:orderSwitch.isOn];
                                  }];
    UIAlertAction *titleButton = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                      [self sortBy:@"title" ascending:orderSwitch.isOn];
                                  }];
    UIAlertAction *subtitleButton = [UIAlertAction
                                  actionWithTitle:@"Subtitle"
                                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive
                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                      [self sortBy:@"subtitle" ascending:orderSwitch.isOn];
                                  }];
    UIAlertAction *cancelButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                   }];

    // add action buttons to the alert
    [alert addAction:createdButton];
    [alert addAction:titleButton];
    [alert addAction:subtitleButton];
    [alert addAction:cancelButton];

    [alert.view addSubview:stackView];

    // center the stack in the alert
    [stackView.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:alert.view.centerXAnchor].active = YES;

    // turn off the autoresizing mask or things get weird
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // use a topAnchor constraint to place the stackview, just below the title
    // TODO:  figure out how to get the height of the alert title (use 64 for now)
    [stackView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:alert.view.topAnchor constant:64].active = YES;

    // layout now to set the view bounds so far - NOTE this does not include the action buttons
    [alert.view layoutIfNeeded];

    // use a height constraint to make the alert view big enough to hold my stack view
    // NOTE:  strange, but this must include the header view AND all the action buttons
    // TODO:  figure out how to get the height of the action buttons (use 52 for each action button for now)
    CGFloat height = alert.view.bounds.size.height + alert.actions.count * 52 + stackView.bounds.size.height;
    [alert.view.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:height].active = YES;

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Recycled Steel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2275199/recycled-steel)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44308192/7345663) above with iOS 13 you can use SF Symbols instead of PNGs. It will solve any scaling issues you might have.

```
    checkbox.imageView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor;
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
        [checkbox setImage: [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"square"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [checkbox setImage: [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"checkmark.square"] forState: UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [checkbox setImage: [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"checkmark.square"] forState: UIControlStateSelected];
    }
```