# Can I add switch to UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

My code of `UIAlertController call`. I need to add switch to alert view.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Поздравляем!", message: "Ваш комментарий сохранен! Если хотите изменить его, выключите и включите переключатель Комментария!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Окей", style: .default) { (action) -> Void in
    let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mailVerify")
    self.present(sb, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You mean you want to downgrade it's compatibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029845/switch-in-uialert-controller-programatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switch in UIAlert Controller programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029845/switch-in-uialert-controller-programatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One posible way to do that is to create your custom UIView with switch and present it modaly instead of UIAlertController. Or try this [Switch in UIAlert Controller programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35029845/switch-in-uialert-controller-programatically)